# How to communicate between a non-component class and an Activity class?

Tags: android, kotlin, callback, listener

I'm trying to listen to an event in an Activity class from a non-Android component class, in particular, I  want to listen to an event that occurs when an Activity gets destroyed (i.e. when onDestroy() gets called).

What I've done to accomplish this is: set up a static function type callback through a companion object, it works like a charm, but something tells me there has to be a better, more proper way to accomplish this communication? I tried looking into the Activity Result API, but that seems to only work between Activities only, I also thought about sending the function type callback to the intent that started the activity, but that requires me to serialize the non-component class and that's not possible in the project I'm working on.

Here's what I've done in my Activity class:

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

companion object {
     lateinit var onActivityDestroyedListener: () -> Unit
}


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // some code  in onCreate()
    }


    override fun onDestroy() {
        // listening to the event 
        onActivityDestroyedListener()
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}
```

and in my non-Android component class:

```
class MyNonComponentClass(private val context: Context) {

fun startMyActivity {
    MyActivity.onActivityDestroyedListener = {
    // some block of code to callback when onActivityDestroyedListener is called
        }

    val intent = Intent(context, MyActivity::class.java).apply {
    flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION
        }
    context.startActivity(intent)
}

}
```

What's a better way to accomplish without a static callback?

Comment: Create MyNonComponentClass object in activity and call its startMyActivity() from onDestroy of activity.

Comment: Android is not designed in a way where your strategy can be a sensible design. Your class has to rely on an activity to be able to get callbacks from the next activity in the stack, but it can't just hold a reference to the parent activity, because that activity can get destroyed and recreated as a new instance while still occupying the same position in the task stack. However, the general convention in modern Android development is not to use multiple activities anyway. Use fragments to represent your different screens.

Comment: If you really want to listen for that *destroyed* event (or any others really) you should probably be looking at *lifecycle-aware components*: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle You can basically register an observer that acts when your Activity's `Lifecycle` hits the `DESTROYED` state